# "AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'colormode'" despite Turtle.py having colormode atttribute

Tags: python, error-handling, attributes

I tried running the code that uses the Turtle library on [this site](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/index.html), shown here,

```
import turtle
import random

def main():
    tList = []
    head = 0
    numTurtles = 10
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.setup(500,500)
    for i in range(numTurtles):
        nt = turtle.Turtle()   # Make a new turtle, initialize values
        nt.setheading(head)
        nt.pensize(2)
        nt.color(random.randrange(256),random.randrange(256),random.randrange(256))
        nt.speed(10)
        wn.tracer(30,0)
        tList.append(nt)       # Add the new turtle to the list
        head = head + 360/numTurtles

    for i in range(100):
        moveTurtles(tList,15,i)

    w = tList[0]
    w.up()
    w.goto(0,40)
    w.write("How to Think Like a ",True,"center","40pt Bold")
    w.goto(0,-35)
    w.write("Computer Scientist",True,"center","40pt Bold")

def moveTurtles(turtleList,dist,angle):
    for turtle in turtleList:   # Make every turtle on the list do the same actions.
        turtle.forward(dist)
        turtle.right(angle)

main()
```

in my own Python editor and I got this error:

> turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (236, 197, 141)

Then, based on this answer on [another site](https://github.com/OpenTechSchool/python-beginners/issues/35), I added in this line before "nt.color(......)"

> nt.colormode(255)

Now it's showing me this error

> AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'colormode'

Okay, so I checked my Python library and looked into the contents of Turtle.py. The colormode() attribute is definitely there. What is making the code able to run on the original site but not on my own computer?

Comment: Can you post,or link to the code you're using?  I have an educated guess, what's wrong, but it's a little hard to be sure with the limited information you've posted.

Comment: Ah, I missed that the code was initially hidden - all I noticed was lots of other links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that your `Turtle` object (`nt`) doesn't have a `colormode` method.  There is one in the turtle module itself though.

So you just need:

```
turtle.colormode(255)
```

instead of

```
nt.colormode(255)
```

**Edit:** To try to clarify your question in the comment, suppose I create a module called `test.py`, with a function, and a class, 'Test':

```
# module test.py

def colormode():
    print("called colormode() function in module test")

class Test
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Now, I use this module:

```
import test

nt = test.Test()  # created an instance of this class (like `turtle.Turtle()`)
# nt.colormode()  # won't work, since `colormode` isn't a method in the `Test` class
test.colormode()  # works, since `colormode` is defined directly in the `test` module
```

Comment: That actually worked, thank you. It does compile that part of the code now, but I just don't quite understand why my original line didn't work if the other "nt" lines have methods that the code doesn't even define beforehand.

Comment: So the colormode() function is out of its scope. That makes complete sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Screen class in turtle module has `colormode()` method.
You can call `screen_object.colormode(255)`.
In your code it would be:

```py
wn.colormode(255)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to set up the colormode() attribute = 255. The class to reference is Screen(), based on your code you referenced this code as wn = turtle.Screen(). In order for you to make your code work, just by adding the following line of code.

wn.colormode(255)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at answering the question, but Meera's answer is the correct one.

The answer is you don't set the colormode on the class (Turtle), the package (turtle), or the instantiated Turtle object (the variable "nt" in your code).

In your code, you created a screen object (see variable "wn")
After you create your screen object, set the colormode on your object.

As stated above in your code you would use the following instruction between lines 7 and 8:

wn.colormode(255)